# Tone Mapping HDR medical image (with opencv) using masks

Tags: python, opencv, hdr

I have mammography images that have a black background and only a small fraction of the image is relevant (breast). I created masks that have 1 in the relevant areas and 0 in the rest. I want to apply the ReinhardToneMapping algorithm, but it shouldn't consider the black areas while processing.

Currently I'm using the OpenCV ReinhardToneMapping https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/dec/classcv_1_1TonemapReinhard.html

But I hope to get better results when using just the relevant pixel info for the Tonemapping

Is there a way to apply the Tonemapping only on the relevant pixels as presented in the mask?